# Secure Cookie on `http://localhost`

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, http, web, cookies

I'm trying to set a secure cookie on `http://localhost:3000`:

> Set-Cookie: loggedUser=brillout; Max-Age=315360000; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure

But Chrome complains:

> This Set-Cookie was blocked because it had the "Secure" attribute but was not received over a secure connection.

Yet, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), it should work:

> A cookie with the Secure attribute is sent to the server only with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol, never with unsecured HTTP (**except on localhost**)

Is it possible to set `Secure` while being `http://localhost`? Developing on `https://localhost` instead of `http://localhost` is not an option.

Comment: i think mixing secure and insecure resources is not an option anymore. I ran into similar issue where we had a secure host (https) trying to get css/js over insecure connection (http). [check this out](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html)

Comment: That makes sense for "real" origins; but for `localhost` Chrome shouldn't really care and be lax.

Comment: Seems there is a change in Chrome 89: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1177877#c7

Comment: This was [a bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1056543&q=localhost%20secure%20cookie&can=2) but is was fixed in version 89 (ticket mentioned by @brillout is a different one that is still open).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing, the Chrome browser stands at Version 100.0.4896.75, the browser is not giving an error or warning. I can easily set cookie from my localhost with attributes given by you.
But If you are still getting errors, you could easily install the SSL certificate on your localhost ([read this blog](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/)) and it will resolve your problem.

Hope this helped you!

Comment: Apparently, this was a Chrome bug that is now fixed. See comment of Didier at OP.