# Run Vue locally on HTTPS in order to use secure cookies

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, cookies, https

I need to set a `secure` flag on cookies, but I can't test it because spinning up a local dev server puts me on `http` and not `https`. When I switch the `config.devServer.useHttps` value to true in my `webpack.conf.dev.js` file, I'm denied access to the website because of Google's security checks. However, as far as I understand it, I will be unable to see secure cookies being set in my DevTools if I'm not on `https`.

How can I ensure I can see those secure flags being added?

I've looked at [this question that unfortunately has no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65006250/secure-cookie-on-http-localhost).

Just FYI, this is how I'm setting the secure flag on the cookie, inline with Google's documentation:

index.html

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-130111108-1');
  gtag('set', {'cookie_flags': 'SameSite=None;Secure'})
</script>
```

Comment: For HTTPS, you need a valid certificate which is recognized by your system. You won't get such a certificate by an official authority (for obvious reasons), but you can generate one by yourself and register it in your OS. Then just configure the certificate in your local dev server config. - Or just don't use Secure on localhost, as it does not really add a benefit locally.